# Find the period of $f(x)=\sin^2(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

$f(x+p)=f(x)$

$\sin^2(x+p)=\sin^2(x)$

$\sin^2(x+p)-\sin^2(x)=0$

$[\sin(x+p)-\sin(x)][\sin(x+p)+\sin(x)]=0$

$\sin(x+p)-\sin(x)=0$

$\sin(x+p)=\sin(x)$

This is the part iI don't get:

$x+p=x+2kπ$

$p=2kπ$

My question: how did we get $x+p=x+2kπ$ from $\sin(x+p)=\sin(x)$

And yeah I know the exercise doesn't end there, but I only want to understand this part first.

Comment: Period od $\sin x$ is $2\pi$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy okay...could you clarify what that has to do with my question? I genuinely don't get it. I know what period is and why $f(x+p)=f(x)$

Comment: The equations show that, as long as $\sin(x+p)+\sin x\neq 0$, we must have $\sin(x+p)=\sin x$. But we know the period of $\sin$, so $p$ must be a multiple of $2\pi$.

Comment: @ElliotG this is how im understanding it: we get the arcsin both sides and the result is $x+p=x$ . But that's it. My question is why isnt p=0. I know that seems absurd, even though we know it's 2π.

Comment: If $\sin y = \sin x$ then $y = x +2k\pi$.  That's all.  That's the only way you can have $\sin y = \sin x$.   so if $\sin x = \sin (x+p)$ we must have $x+p= x+2k$.

Comment: $p\ne 0$ because the definition of period wouldn't allow it.  *Every* function has it true that $f(x) = f(x+0)$.  So talking of a period of $0$ would be pointless and tell us nothing.  so $p$ is defined as the least positive value (if such exists) where $f(x+p) = f(x)$ for all $x$.  If no such $p$ exist the function isn't periodic.  if no *smallest* postive $p$ exists but some non zero $p$ exist it can be shown the entire function is constant.

Comment: @fleablood so you're telling me that it's always x(or whatever) + the period of the function wrapping that x(or whatever)?

Comment: "o you're telling me that it's always x(or whatever) + the period of the function wrapping that x(or whatever)? "  I don''t understand what you are asking.  But $\sin y = \sin x$ means either $y = x + 2k\pi$ or $y = (2k+1)\pi - x$.  If we replace $y$ with $x + p$ we get either $x+p = x+2k\pi$ or $x+p = (2k+1)\pi -x$.  so either $p=2k\pi$ or $p =(2k+1)\pi -2x$. but we need this to be true for all $x$ so the second option is no good.  so $p = 2k\pi$.

Comment: @fleablood Not quite true. $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\in\Bbb Q\\0&x\notin\Bbb Q\end{cases}$ has $f(x+p)=f(x)$ for all $p\in\Bbb Q$, hence no smallest positive $p$ exists, but $f$ is not constant.

Comment: Argh.... I should have trusted my gut that that seemed too pat.  ... so I'm not one hundred percent sure what the terminology of these infinitesimally periodic functions is.  Do we say "$f$ is periodic with any rational period" or do we say this fails to be periodic because a periodic function must have a distinct period or is there some other terminology.

Comment: Okay, a few minutes of research.  If $f(x+p) = f(x)$ for all $x$ then $f$ is periodic and $p$ is *a* period.  To be periodic $f$ must repeat at regular *intervals* and $x$ to $x+0$ is not an interval so periods are non-zero.  We refer to "the" period if there is a "fundamental" smallest period but not all periodic functions have "the" fundamental period.  (Ex: $f(x) =7$ will have $f(x+p)=f(x)$ for all $x$ and all $p$ so any value is *a* period but there is no "the" period.  Hagen von Eitzen is a periodic function for which every rational is *a* period but there is no "the" period.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question directly, suppose $\sin^2x $ is periodic with period $p$.  We need to find the smallest $p > 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
\sin^2(x+p) = \sin^2 x \tag{1}\label{eq1}
\end{equation}
for all $x$, if such exists.

**Method 1**:
$\cos 2x = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x = 1 - 2\sin^2 x$.  Therefore, $\sin^2x = \frac{1}{2}\Big( 1 - \cos2x \Big)$.  If you accept that $\sin$ and $\cos$ are both periodic with period $2\pi$ it is thus apparent that $\sin^2x$ is also periodic with period $\pi$.

**Method 2**:
Suppose $\sin^2x$ is periodic with period $p$.  Then taking $x=0$ in equation \eqref{eq1} gives $\sin^2 p = 0$.  Now we are only interested in the smallest positive $p$ and therefore we must have $p \geqslant \pi$ since $\pi$ is the smallest positive zero of $\sin x$.  Now take $p = \pi$.
\begin{align}
\sin^2(x+\pi) -\sin^2 x &= \Big(\sin(x+\pi)-\sin(x)\Big)\Big(\sin(x+\pi) +\sin (x)\Big) \\
&= \Big(\sin x \cos \pi + \cos x \sin \pi - \sin x\Big)\Big(\sin x \cos \pi + \cos x \sin \pi + \sin x\Big) \\
&=\Big(-\sin x - \sin x\Big)\Big(-\sin x + \sin x\Big) \\
&=0
\end{align}
So we have $\sin^2(x+\pi) = \sin^2(x) $ for all $x$ and $\pi$ is the smallest number with this property so $\sin^2 x$ is periodic with period is $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really helpful. +1

Comment: No problem.  Feel free to accept it if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

That is not quite correct, as we have the basic equivalence for equations in sines:
$$\sin x=\sin y\iff \begin{cases}x\equiv y\mod 2\pi &\text{or} \\x\equiv \pi -y\mod 2\pi.\end{cases}$$

The initial equation can also be solved  linearising both sides:

$$\sin^2(x+p)=\sin^2x\equiv \frac{1-\cos 2(x+p)}{2}=\frac{1-\cos2x}{2}\iff =\cos 2(x+p)=\cos 2x\\\iff 2(x+p)\equiv \pm 2x\mod 2\pi.$$

Comment: Yeah k should always be the lowest>0 number possible. That's not my concern .

Comment: It  is usually simpler to to solve with congruences, in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, online teaching man. Electricity cut off and now I'm having to learn these all by myself...

Answer (score 0):

The equation $f(x+p) = f(x)$ is the definition of a periodic function, which you have used on $f(x) = \sin^2(x)$ to reach the conclusion that $\sin(x+p) = \sin(x)$ must hold. If it was another function that we knew nothing about, we couldn't really go any further but say that $\sin^2(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ have the same period. But because this is the *sine* function which we understand very well, we know that its period is $2\pi$. Thus, the output of the function is repeated at $2\pi,4\pi,6\pi$... Hence we can say that the input of the function must satisfy $x+p=x+2k\pi$.

To give a different example.. say we arrived to the case where we had $\tan(x+p) = \tan(x)$ instead. Here, we know that the period of $tan$ is $\pi$, so we can conclude that $x+p=x+k\pi$.

Comment: However, $\sin x$ and $\sin^2x$ do *not* have the same period.

Answer (score 0):

Before we start consider this preliminary question.

> If $\sin a = \sin b$ solve for $b$ in terms of $a$.

Well if $(\cos a, \sin b) = (x,y)$ there is only one other point of a circle with the same $y$ value.  That would be $(-x,y)$ and that occurs if $b = \pi - a$.

so if $0\le a,b < 2\pi$ then only options are $b= a$ or $b = \pi -a$.  And if we remove the restrictions we have $b = a +2k\pi$ or $b= (2k+1)\pi -a$ for so integer $k$.

....

Now we do your question.

Suppose $\sin (x+p) = \sin x$ for *all* $x$.

Let $y = x+p$ and we have $\sin(y) = \sin x$ and we just did that.  $y = x +p = x +2k\pi$ or $y=x+p= (2k+1)\pi - x$.

In the first case we have $p =2k\pi$.  And in the second case $p=(2k+1)\pi - 2x$ but that makes $p$ dependent upon $x$ and won't have a single value for every possible $x$.

so if $p$ is a period it must be the first case and $p = 2k\pi$ for some $k$.  And to find "the" period we need the smallest positive value of $2k\pi$ so that $\sin^2(x+2k\pi) = \sin^2 x$ and as $k=1$ *works* that's the smallest.

Not $k=0$ and $p =0$ is not an acceptable value for a period.  Claiming a function "has period $0$" would be to so "$f(x) = f(x+0)$ for all $x$" and that's....  well, that's just pointless.